Add Functional layer/model to Sequential model
Since I didn't find any answer in official documentation or other questions I'm asking here: are there any caveats in terms of optimization / serialization / other aspects when we add a Functional layer/model to a Sequential model? The added model should of course have one input and one output. What I mean by this is the following:
input_shape = ...

def create_functional_model():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(input_shape))
    # Your functional model logic here
    outputs = ...
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

functional_model = create_functional_model()

sequential_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
sequential_model.add(tf.keras.Input(input_shape))
sequential_model.add(functional_model)

When I try to run the code similar to this, it runs as expected, but I'm wondering whether it can cause potential troubles for more complex / nested models.
Tensorflow docs only mention using models defined using Sequential API or Functional API in the models defined using Subclassing API, but not in Sequential API.

No, Keras models are layers in that the model class inherits from the layer class. So a model can work as a layer as part of another model.
